# Why is my callback not taking the result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, callback, settimeout

```
let result;

function HelloFunction(callbackfn){
    setTimeout(() => result = 50 ,2000);
    callbackfn(result);
};

HelloFunction((a) => console.log(`Result is ${a}`));
```

Output: Result is undefined. Why not Result is 50 as it's a callback

Comment: It's because you invoke `callbackfn()` ***before*** you set the value of `result`. Remember, `result` is only set after the 2sec delay, yet the callback is called immediately. You need to change your logic to put the callback in the timeout, after setting the value of `result`: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4svdmbho/

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan